# Quickblox-android join chat group is not working

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

i have integrated quickblox android SDk in my app and there are more than 500 dialogs group in list and when i try to join any group chat room, I am not getting entered in either of `onSuccess()` and `onError()` ,control flow just goes bypassing callback methods by using below code.

```
    qbChatDialog.initForChat(QBChatService.getInstance());
    qbChatDialog.addMessageListener(chatMessageListener);

    DiscussionHistory discussionHistory = new DiscussionHistory();
    discussionHistory.setMaxStanzas(0);

    if (!qbChatDialog.isJoined()) {
        qbChatDialog.join(discussionHistory, new QBEntityCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object o, Bundle bundle) {
                if (qbChatDialog != null) {
                    getMessage(qbChatDialog, false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                Log.e("QB Join", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(QBChatActivity.this, "" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    } else {
        if (qbChatDialog != null) {
            getMessage(qbChatDialog, false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure all of your Dialogs are type of `QBDialogType.PUBLIC_GROUP` ?

Comment: the type is QBDialogType.GROUP

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is Group type . 
if you want to create a public group which anyone can join then you should create with **QBDialogType.PUBLIC_GROUP**.
In case of **QBDialogType.GROUP** participants should be add at the time of creation and only those participants can join the group which were added .

Solution is create your dialog with type **QBDialogType.PUBLIC_GROUP** if you want it to public .

```
QBChatDialog qbChatDialog=new QBChatDialog();
qbChatDialog.setType(QBDialogType.PUBLIC_GROUP);// For public group
qbChatDialog.setType(QBDialogType.GROUP);// For private group
```

Comment: Did you add the current user to group at the time of creation? or add as participant later by creator ? Try to debug getOccupants() on dialog and see if your id is in list or not .

Comment: add user during creation, let me clear you i have around more than 500 dialog group list and when i try to join in any group then callback never calls, and it when into endless loading. and yes im in the occupant list

Comment: Ok this seems weird. First make sure you are part of dialog by debugging getOccupants() on dialog . Second instead of using SDk method use Rest API just for debugging purpose . Also check the XMPP **logs** during calling Join .

Comment: ok i found that, in my project 'auto_join' was 'true', and as i have more than 500 dialogs groups, so when i retrieve all groups dialog it takes lots of time for numerous synchronous join attempts in background hence it was not working in my case, so after i have set  'auto_join' as 'false' and then when i try to join any single group dialog, it was successfull., thanks for your effort

Comment: I too had configurationBuilder.setAutojoinEnabled(true);` but i don't faced the same problem . Why ?